# Bootstrap or css: Center align texts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some words which are aligned left and right of a "|". In each line the pipes should be centered. This is what I want (each line is centered):

```
                     small text | little more text
               longer text left | a word
```

If I use a centered div around each line I get this (what I do not want):

```
                  small text | little more text
                    longer text left | a word
```

How can I achieve that?

This would be a solution when I used old school tables https://jsfiddle.net/wL5sjkn4/1/ :

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="*" align="right">Links</td>
        <td width="20px" align="center">|</td>
        <td width="*" align="left">Rechts Lorem Lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="*" align="right">Links Lorem Lorem</td>
        <td width="20px" align="center">|</td>
        <td width="*" align="left">Rechts</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right" style="background-color:lavender;">Lorem</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right" style="background-color:lavender;">Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is solution, I think?
See in full screen, change it according to your requirement.

Comment: No, that is NOT what I meant, but this was one of my attempts. It is important to see that I want to have "3 columns" per line - the middle one only contains the pipe symbol ( | ). And this has to be centered in each line

Comment: I updated m question with a table "solution" - but I would like to do that using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Text alignment aligns text but is unaware of the context of it, doesn't know that it should align according to a certain character. Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dxL6s4tn/ for examples and possible solutions.

This is a *part* of the fiddle:

html

```
<!-- Preformatted monotype font -->
<section class="pre-mono">
      small text | little more text
longer text left | a word
</section>
```

css

```
.pre-mono {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Mohammed's answer will work as well but requires you to alter you HTML structure, this is a better solution if you're dealing with an actual markup rather than plain text.

Comment: Well, in the fiddle I do not see the part I asked for. I edited my question.